# Java Regular Expression: Remove Dashes and Whitespace Not Working

Tags: java, regex

I need to remove all dashes and whitespace. I'm having trouble with this regexp, it's not working:

```
private static final String USZIPCODE_REMOVE_REGEXP = "[\\-\\s]";

zipCode.replaceAll(USZIPCODE_REMOVE_REGEXP, "");
```

The debugger shows an unchanged result:

Input:

```
12345---6789
```

Output:

```
12345---6789
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `String` object is immutable in Java -- you need to assign the new value to another string (you can use the same variable):

```
zipCode = zipCode.replaceAll(USZIPCODE_REMOVE_REGEXP, "");
```

Comment: great, that's what it was.